# Biblatex - Use Slash (/) to divive authors names within text

Tags: biblatex

the guidelines for my university paper want citation like this:

Within the text:

1 author: Johnson (2018) states that...  or "blahblah" (Johnson 2018).

2 authors: Johnson/Smith (2017) mention ... or "blabla" (Johnson/Smith 2017).

more authors: Johnson et al. (2019) ... or "blabla" (Johnson et al. 2019).

Scenario 1 and 3 work fine for me, but when using 2 authors, Biblatex is sparating with "and" (Johnson and Smith (2017)) instead of the slash I want.

Is there a way to renew the command?

In the bibliography, the "and" should stay, because there the guidelines require it.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
the package settings and used commands look like this:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can change the name delimiter just for the document body and retain the original definition for the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}



\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}

normal document text

\cite{sigfridsson}


\endgroup
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly, that does not work for me. Neither with \textcite nor with \cite or \parencite.

Comment: @spqx That's not very helpful information. Can you make a document that shows how it is not working for you?

Comment: I got the "/" to work, I hat to paste the renowcommands after my \begintitling and \endtitling-environment.
Another problem occured: Instead of Sigfridson/Ryde it shows E. Sigfridson/U. Ryde. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: With a current system you could use the context-sensitive `\DeclareDelimFormat` instead of grouped `\renewcommand`s. Unfortunately, the default set-up means that this will require some code duplication...

Answer (score 0):

With more recent versions of `biblatex` I recommend you use that `multinamdelim` and `finalnamedelim` are context-sensitive delimiters that can be redefine with `\DeclareDelimFormat`.

Unfortunately, the defaults are so that the safest definition involves copying the original definition, which means that the code is a bit longer than in [user191948](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/191948/user191948)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498219/35864)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson/Ryde 1998//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]