# Conforming citation call-outs to my university's standards: Slashes instead of commas

Tags: citing, natbib

My university has their own rules for citation call-outs, and I have to change the way my citations look. I'm currently using `natbib` and my citations look like this:

```
(AUTHOR YEAR, PAGES)
```

and for multiple authors like this

```
(AUTHOR1 et al., YEAR, PAGES) or (AUTHOR1, AUTHOR2 & AUTHOR3, YEAR, PAGES)
```

However, they're supposed to look like

```
(AUTHOR YEAR: PAGES)
```

and

```
(AUTHOR1/AUTHOR2/AUTHOR3 YEAR: PAGES)
```

I cite as follows:

```
\citep[pages]{key}
\citep*[pages]{key}
```

---

Edit: I use the `agsm` bibliography style, as I'm supposed to cite according to Harvard with those exceptions mentioned.

To clarify further:
I'm supposed to write "et al." if there are *more than three* authors involved; if there are fewer than four I'm supposed to separate their surnames by a slash like

```
(AUTHOR1/AUTHOR2/AUTHOR3 YEAR: PAGES)
```

I dug further in the natbib documentation to find

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={: },round,aysep={},yysep={;}}
```

which replaces the comma but still not the slash when using the "\citep*"-command

---

Edit2: To avoid further confusion, here's an example of how it should look:

> Die Existenz einer Skala muss erst bewiesen werden (Schell/Hill/Esser 2011: 132).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. `natbib` is just the package that does the formatting, but the formatting itself is determined by the bibliography style you are using, which you haven't told us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does `AUTHOR1/AUTHOR2/AUTHOR3` imply (a) no "et al."-type truncating of the list of surnames (at least for pieces with exactly three authors) and (b) mandatory use of `/` as the separator *between* surnames instead of commas and the word "and"? Please confirm. Please also confirm that there is supposed to be no year information after `AUTHOR1/AUTHOR2/AUTHOR3`.

Comment: @Mico I confirm that there needs to be a "/" for author separation for a citation that includes two or three authors. Et al. is only allowed for four or more authors. The year however needs to be there, that was my mistake and I edited it.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78056633/2777074

Comment: Your claim that "I use agsm as bibliography style, as I'm supposed to cite according to Harvard" verges on being badly misleading. "Harvard" (in the present context) is just a synonym for "author-year"-style citation call-outs. Moreover, `agsm` is but one of many, many bibliography styles that implements "harvard". Now,  the `agsm` style is known to be a rather quirky bibliography style. Is it in your power to employ a less-quirky style?

Comment: First, I did not crosspost, as the question here goes a lot further than the other one I posted (and the other one is solved by now). And for the bib style: I choose agsm, because the style seemed to work with what I needed, first. I'm no expert and tend to stick with one thing to not overcomplicate things. Is there another style that lets me choose a "/" instead of a ","-separation?

Comment: @Pywide - A complicating factor is that you actually need to implement 2 changes, and not just 1 change, to what's generally considered to be a set of defaults. First, you want slashes rather than commas as the separator between authors' surnames. Second, the "et al"-type truncation of lists of surnames is only supposed to kick in for publications with more than 3 authors, rather than with for publications for 3 or more authors. Rather than stick with the `natbib` citation management package and seek to modify an existing BibTeX bibliography style, you may be better off switching to biblatex.

Comment: @Pywide (continuation of preceding comment) See, e.g., the posting [Biblatex - Use Slash (/) to divive authors names within text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498215/5001) for a solution to the slash-divider problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you currently load the `natbib` package with the options `authoryear` and `round`. You need to run

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={}, notesep={:\space}}
```

as well in order to (a) remove the comma as the separator between the author and the year group and (b) get a semicolon to function as the separator between the year and the note group.

[image]

The separator between authors' surnames is determined by the bibliography style you employ, about which you have told us nothing so far.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
%% create a test bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa:3001, author = "Anna Atkins",
      title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}, notesep={:\space}} % <-- new
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bibligraphy style

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citep[pp.\ 3--5]{aa:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```